# Swift - in app purchase - load products from mysql database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, paypal

hi i have read in this http://www.raywenderlich.com/105365/in-app-purchases-tutorial-getting-started

but I want to do one application that can add story contents. so if anyone need to read my story content, he need to pay. so that I have created php website to allow me to add story by adding title, contents, price. then in my app, it loads data from mysql database. how can i allow user to but my story using in app purchase. because in the tutorial it said: I can create in-app-purchase consumable item in itunes connect then reload those item in my app. buy for me it is not I want. I want to control it from php server so i can insert more story or delete story. anyone can give me idea. can i do this using in-app-purchase or i need to sell my story using paypal or other framework for selling product. thank in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the story is a digital product and consumed in the app then you need to use in-app purchases.

You can only add new in-app purchases each time you release an update to the app, because they are reviewed as part of Apples approval process.

It may be possible that you can have lots of items defined in iTunes connect that you don't make available immediately, though the Apple review would need to be able to see them all or you would likely get rejected.

You probably can't create generic sale items as restoring purchases wouldn't work (at least any attempt at this approach would need to be discussed with apple in advance).

Comment: thank for answer. so it is impossible to dynamically add in-app-purchase items from mysql database.

Comment: Not impossible, but they all need to be reviewed by Apple before you can use them, so you would need to show them and they would need to work during review and then you would need to hide them.